# How to get data From Status bar and disable it?

Tags: android

I am  creating a custom lock screen so that in my activity the Status
bar won't be there.

At the mean time i want to get the the status bar notifications such
as missed calls, new chat messages, new emails, new voice-mail, etc...

How to implement this?
please give me a hint

Comment: Your first line confuses me, a custom lock screen and the status bar have very little to do with eachother. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: simply saying, can i  get the the status bar notifications such as missed calls, new chat messages, new emails, new voice-mail, etc... in my own activity